# Gtk gchar labelling

Tags: c, gtk

I keep getting this error and weird gibberish when I try to run the following snippet of code:

ERROR is:

**(foo:11333): Pango-WARNING **: Invalid UTF-8 string passed to pango_layout_set_text()**

Structure definition:

```
typedef struct chat_info ChatInfo;
struct chat_info {
  GtkWidget *text_line1;
  GtkWidget *text_line2;
  GtkWidget *text_line3;
  GtkWidget *entry;

};
```

And this code makes the weird gibberish come out on the third label (second label is empty)

```
static void send_message(GtkWidget *window, gpointer data){
    GuiInfo *g = (GuiInfo *) data;


    ChatInfo *c = g->chat;

    const gchar *message = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(c->entry));  
    const gchar *oldtext1 = gtk_label_get_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line1);
    const gchar *oldtext2 = gtk_label_get_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line2);

    gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line1, message);
    gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line2, oldtext1);
    gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line3, oldtext2);


}
```

I looked up the error, and I'm guessing it's probably due to something like giving a pointer address when I should be giving a gchar string? Everything looks right though.

Comment: Can you add the code that calls send_message? Is it the callback to a signal? Are you getting any other error messages before this?

Comment: Also, you should use GTK_LABEL (c->text_line1), instead of (GtkLabel *) as that will add some other error checking

Comment: The error is quite clear: you are passing non-UTF8 to `gtk_label_set_text`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is that the memory that's coming back from your `_get_text()` calls is being freed by `GtkLabel` before you use it again by you calling `_set_text()`.

For example when you call `gtk_label_set_text(c->text_line1, message)` that renders the pointer you retrieved into `oldtext1` invalid (the call to `gtk_label_get_text()` returns a pointer to the internal copy of the string).

Now you can fix this by reordering your code to remove that dependency:

```
gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line3, oldtext2);
gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line2, oldtext1);
gtk_label_set_text( (GtkLabel *) c->text_line1, message);
```

Or perhaps for readability you should `strdup()` the strings you get from `_get_text()` and then pass those into `_set_text()` and free those later.